# JSON parsing in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

I need to do parsing for this JSON string and need to get all the values inside Iphone like width,url etc , any suggestions

```
[[
  {
    "id" : "1ab66b240b5441a35f1c963c802ebc23",
    "sizes" : {
      "IPhone" : {
        "width" : 288,
        "actualHeight" : 288,
        "sizeName" : "IPhone",
        "url" : "abc1.jpg",
        "actualWidth" : 288,
        "height" : 360
      },
      "IPhone2" : {
        "width" : 164,
        "actualHeight" : 164,
        "sizeName" : "Large",
        "url" : "https:abc.jpg",
        "actualWidth" : 164,
        "height" : 205
      },
     }
  }
]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reading JSON is pretty easy:

`{}` is dictionary, `[]` is array, so all nested collection types are dictionaries:

For convenience declare a type alias:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String : Any]
```

---

```
if let image = aObject["image"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let sizes = image["sizes"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let xLarge = sizes["XLarge"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let url = xLarge["url"] as? String {
      print(url)
}
```

PS: Don't use ugly C-style index based `for` loops in Swift, this is the recommended way:

```
for aObject in arrJSON as! [JSONDictionary] {
```

and delete the next line `let aObject = ....`

Answer (score 1):

Used [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse the values and it worked fine.

> SwiftyJSON makes it easy to deal with JSON data in Swift. For example:
>
> ```
> let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
> if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
>   //Now you got your value
> }
> ```